Can't get github action to initiate
I'm trying to build a Github page from code that I copied from someone else's repository (I'm completely new to all software involved here). The code contained here is in my workflows folder:
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '3'
      - name: Update Gem
        run: gem update --system
      - name: Install Gems
        run: bundle install
      - name: Build Jekyll
        run: bundle exec jekyll build

When I push master (I've confirmed I am on the branch master), nothing happens. I tried to manually trigger a build of the site and it's now a queued workflow that I can't cancel (there were previous build attempts that did happen but failed because of my tinkering with the code). Here's a picture of the error message. I can locally build the site on my machine and see it by running
bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload

Any advice?

Maybe it was waiting for a runner and something went wrong on their side. I would try restarting the workflow or trying a different image so it would connect to a different runner..

@Sasha Can you give any guidance on how to do that? I'm completely new to all of this. Honestly I'm not sure how the workflow pictured was created or if it's what I wanted. I was hoping that everything would just correctly build when I pushed the branch.

Yes, definitely. And you are right, it should work as you expect. I would start with disabling and enabling the workflow on this page: https://github.com/jonhillery/jonhillery.github.io/actions/workflows/pages/pages-build-deployment (triple dots button next to the workflow name)

It seems I can't disable the workflow. Maybe there no longer is a workflow? This is what I see: https://i.sstatic.net/y6o7Kb0w.png

Interesting  Also if you open summary for this run it shows a failed build.. Maybe another thing would be to push a small update and see what happens?

I pushed a small change. Nothing changed or happened on the actions page and the site still wasn't built. Perhaps I just need to read a lot more about Github workflows to get anywhere.

I think it is something on GH side. Maybe try to make a branch with a small change, push it, create a PR, merge it and see if GH likes it better

I was able to get the action to finally execute by changing the run condition to
on: [push]

I still don't know why it wasn't working for the master branch.

Glad you figured it out! What puzzles me though is that you had the push configured for the master branch before and it should have worked according to their docs (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-when-your-workflow-runs/triggering-a-workflow#using-filters) but GH did not respect it for some reason. Anyway, congrats!

https://www.githubstatus.com/ shows that there was some issue with PRs yesterday which has been resolved now. See https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/rzqy51mc72dx for details. Not sure whether your issue is directly related to that or not. You may correlate the timestamps of this incident and your workflows run(s).
